# Usage of the preposition "à"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I really don't know if the title is right, please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm correcting my French coursework with a friend who is fluent in French.

To my knowledge the sentences:

'C'est parce que je suis toujours sur mon ordinateur à jouer aux jeux vidéo.'

and

'Je ne vais à pied que à l'école'

Are right, according to me and my French teacher, who I suppose doesn't speak fluent French, however the correct way - Or best - of saying these are:

'C'est parce que je suis toujours sur mon ordinateur à jouer aux jeux vidéo.'

and

'Je ne vais qu'à l'école à pied.'

What does the 'à' function as in the sentences, she said it was a pronoun, but one, I don't know what a pronoun is, and two she didn't know how to explain any more. The 'à' in "qu'à" and in "ordinateur a jouer"

Comment: /a jouer/ is not right. it sounds like Portuguese to me. /Está sempre a jogar/Also, /a/ is not a pronoun in French, neither is à, à is a preposition and /a/ doesn't exist in French on its own as a word. And sur mon ordinateur is from English: on the computer and it is not idiomatic in French. "toujours accroché à mon ordinateur" would work. the /a/ should be: en train de jouer aux jeux vidéo. Pronouns replace nouns: Marie, elle; Jean, il;Marie et Jean: Ils, etc. (only one example)

Comment: @Lambie "être à + infinitive" is correct French.

Comment: @jlliagre être à l'école, mais pas /être à jouer/....être à jouer sur mon ordinateur is not correct French. ser a + infinitive in Portuguese is correct Portuguese. commencer à jouer, commencer à comprendre, s'attendre à aller are all correct French. Penser à faire le travail. Certain verbs take à followed by the infinitive.

Comment: Please see the list of verbs that can take à plus infinitive: http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-verbes-qui-se-construisent-avec-a-infinitif-ou-de-infinitif-86346139.html

Comment: @Lambie This construction that also exists in Italian and Spanish (*sono a giocare* / *estoy a jugar*) is correct in French too. Have a look to the tlfi [`à` entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) : − être à + inf.« être en train de », périphrase exprimant l'aspect duratif :
9. Tous deux devaient être à causer sous le hangar, lorsque lui s'était avancé pour appeler le sous-chef. É. Zola, La Bête humaine,1890, p. 59.

Comment: @Lambie and of course, the expression *Il passe son temps à jouer sur son ordinateur* is very common French.

Comment: passer à n'est pas: être + infinitif. Je veux bien que "Tous deux etc" de votre phrase marche mais personne ne ***parle*** comme ça. Et la question portait sur cela. Des structures utilisées courramment, pas de phrases litéraires d'un Zola.

Comment: Et personne a rien dit contre: passer son temps à faire n'importe quoi.

Comment: You must write "à". Because "a" is the verb (avoir), not the preposition. Accent is very important here.

Comment: It's very common to say something like *"C'est parce que je suis toujours sur mon ordinateur à jouer aux jeux vidéo"*. Very. Common.

Answer (score 3):

*À* (with a grave accent please) is a preposition, not a pronoun.

Your first sentence is correct French, here *à jouer* is equivalent — See [tlfi être III.- B.- 3. a)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) and [Dictionnaire des pièges et difficultés de la langue française](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KOINHRkfU_oC&pg=PA367&lpg=PA367&dq=%C3%AAtre%20%C3%A0%20%2B%20infinitif,%20au%20sens%20de%20%22%C3%AAtre%20en%20train%20de%22%20%3D%20Tour%20admis%20dans%20la&source=bl&ots=5csDLdcNiC&sig=DgIdRmkSQFoRRBp5aPJzKtQZ7IM&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifyJeugoXRAhXGuBQKHUNCCvQQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%C3%AAtre%20%C3%A0%20%2B%20infinitif%2C%20au%20sens%20de%20%22%C3%AAtre%20en%20train%20de%22%20%3D%20Tour%20admis%20dans%20la&f=false) — to *en train de jouer*:

> C'est parce que je suis toujours sur mon ordinateur à jouer aux jeux vidéo.

More idiomatic ways would be:

> C'est parce que je suis toujours à jouer aux jeux vidéo sur mon ordinateur.
>
> C'est parce que je suis toujours en train de jouer aux jeux vidéo sur mon ordinateur.

Both of your remaining attempts are odd. Depending on what you want to say, that should be:

> Je ne vais à l'école qu'à pied. (→ I only go to school by walking.)

or better (thanks to @Lambie)

> Je vais toujours à l'école à pied. (→ I always go to school by walking.)

or

> Je ne vais à pied qu'à l'école. (→ Except when I go to school, I never walk.)

Comment: In more context, 'En ce moment, je ne fais pas assez d'exercice. Je ne vais qu'a l'école à pied.' I'm trying to say the only exercise I do is walking to school at the moment.

Comment: That sentence sounds better reordered: *Je ne vais à pied qu'à l'école*.

Comment: ***I don't go to school but walking*** is not grammatical in English. ***Outside going to school*** is also not grammatical. And the ***usual spoken way of saying this*** in French is: ***Je vais toujours à l'ecole à pied***. Because the other ways are very awkward. And no one says: je suis toujours à jouer  in modern French.

Comment: @Lambie About my poor English, fair enough, you are welcome to provide an idiomatic and grammatical translation. I definitely say and hear, *elle est toujours dans sa chambre à jouer sur sa console*.

Comment: I'm not sure about my last point, I'm not trying to say: 'I only ever walk to school' but rather making the point that that's the only exercise I do.

Comment: Ah, elle est toujours DANS SA CHAMBRE à jouer sur. Et non pas: être sans rien à + infinitif!

Comment: @Lambie Plus récent que Zola: http://vieuxcoq.eklablog.com/les-femmes-sont-toujours-a-se-plaindre-et-pourtant-a114953978 https://twitter.com/libredesprit593/status/732878410427584513

Comment: @T.Hep If you want to say that's the only exercise you do, just say it! *Mon seul exercice physique, c'est d'aller à l'école à pied !*

Comment: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soit (rechercher "être en train", partie **B-3.a)**) ainsi que https://books.google.fr/books?id=KOINHRkfU_oC&pg=PA367&lpg=PA367&dq=%C3%AAtre+%C3%A0+%2B+infinitif,+au+sens+de+%22%C3%AAtre+en+train+de%22+%3D+Tour+admis+dans+la&source=bl&ots=5csDLdcNiC&sig=DgIdRmkSQFoRRBp5aPJzKtQZ7IM&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifyJeugoXRAhXGuBQKHUNCCvQQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%C3%AAtre%20%C3%A0%20%2B%20infinitif%2C%20au%20sens%20de%20%22%C3%AAtre%20en%20train%20de%22%20%3D%20Tour%20admis%20dans%20la&f=false partie 6

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Thanks! Links added.